# whats wrong with my implementation of Tree in java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, linked-list

Im trying to implement a Tree that holds the list of the children of a given node. When I try output the size in my main method it returns 1. Can anyone see if theres anything wrong with my createNode method? And before anyone gets angry, I'm just including all of my code so that you can see what I'm trying to do :)

```
public class LinkedTree<E> implements Tree<E> {

    protected TreePosition<E> root; // reference to the root
    protected int size; // number of nodes

    public LinkedTree() {
        root = null; // start with an empty tree
        size = 0;
    }

    /** Returns the number of nodes in the tree. */
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /** Returns whether the tree is empty. */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (size == 0);
    }

    /** Returns whether a node is internal. */
    public boolean isInternal(Position<E> v) throws InvalidPositionException {
        return !isExternal(v);
    }

    /** Returns whether a node is external. */
    public boolean isExternal(Position<E> v) throws InvalidPositionException {
        TreePosition<E> vv = checkPosition(v); // auxiliary method
        return (vv.getChildren() == null) || vv.getChildren().isEmpty();
    }

    /** Returns whether a node is the root. */
    public boolean isRoot(Position<E> v) throws InvalidPositionException {
        checkPosition(v);
        return (v == root());
    }

    /** Returns the root of the tree. */
    public Position<E> root() throws EmptyTreeException {
        if (root == null)
            throw new EmptyTreeException("The tree is empty");
        return root;
    }


    /** Returns the parent of a node. */
    public Position<E> parent(Position<E> v) throws InvalidPositionException,
            BoundaryViolationException {
        TreePosition<E> vv = checkPosition(v);
        Position<E> parentPos = vv.getParent();
        if (parentPos == null)
            throw new BoundaryViolationException("No parent");
        return parentPos;
    }

    /** Returns an iterable collection of the children of a node. */
    public Iterable<Position<E>> children(Position<E> v)
            throws InvalidPositionException {
        TreePosition<E> vv = checkPosition(v);
        if (isExternal(v))
            throw new InvalidPositionException(
                    "External nodes have no children");
        return vv.getChildren();
    }

    /** Returns an iterable collection of the tree nodes. */
    public Iterable<Position<E>> positions() {
        PositionList<Position<E>> positions = new NodePositionList<Position<E>>();
        if (size != 0)
            preorderPositions(root(), positions); // assign positions in
                                                    // preorder
        return positions;
    }

    /** Returns an iterator of the elements stored at the nodes */
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        Iterable<Position<E>> positions = positions();
        PositionList<E> elements = new NodePositionList<E>();
        for (Position<E> pos : positions)
            elements.addLast(pos.element());
        return elements.iterator(); // An iterator of elements
    }

    /** Replaces the element at a node. */
    public E replace(Position<E> v, E o) throws InvalidPositionException {
        TreePosition<E> vv = checkPosition(v);
        E temp = v.element();
        vv.setElement(o);
        return temp;
    }


    /** Adds a root node to an empty tree */
    public Position<E> addRoot(E e) throws NonEmptyTreeException {
        if (!isEmpty())
            throw new NonEmptyTreeException("Tree already has a root");
        size = 1;
        root = createNode(e, null, null);
        return root;
    }

    /** Swap the elements at two nodes */
    public void swapElements(Position<E> v, Position<E> w)
            throws InvalidPositionException {
        TreePosition<E> vv = checkPosition(v);
        TreePosition<E> ww = checkPosition(w);
        E temp = w.element();
        ww.setElement(v.element());
        vv.setElement(temp);
    }


    /** If v is a good tree node, cast to TreePosition, else throw exception */
    protected TreePosition<E> checkPosition(Position<E> v)
            throws InvalidPositionException {
        if (v == null || !(v instanceof TreePosition))
            throw new InvalidPositionException("The position is invalid");
        return (TreePosition<E>) v;
    }

    /** Creates a new tree node */
    protected TreePosition<E> createNode(E element, TreePosition<E> parent,
            PositionList<Position<E>> children) {
        return new TreeNode<E>(element, parent, children);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a list storing the the nodes in the subtree of a node, ordered
     * according to the preorder traversal of the subtree.
     */
    protected void preorderPositions(Position<E> v,
            PositionList<Position<E>> pos) throws InvalidPositionException {
        pos.addLast(v);
        for (Position<E> w : children(v))
            preorderPositions(w, pos); // recurse on each child
    }

    public Iterator<E> iteratorO() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean islnternal(Position<E> v) throws InvalidPositionException {
        return false;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedTree<Character> T = new LinkedTree();

        // add root
        T.addRoot('A');

        // add children of root
        T.createNode('B', (TreeNode) (T.root()), new NodePositionList());
        TreePosition C = T.createNode('C', (TreeNode) (T.root()),
                new NodePositionList());
        T.createNode('D', (TreeNode) (T.root()), new NodePositionList());

        // add children of node C

        T.createNode('E', C, new NodePositionList());
        TreePosition F = T.createNode('F', C, new NodePositionList());
        T.createNode('G', C, new NodePositionList());

        // add childrn of Node F
        T.createNode('H', F, new NodePositionList());
        T.createNode('I', F, new NodePositionList());

        // print out tree

        System.out.println("Size = " + T.size());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. The value of `size` is not set adequately. There are only two places where size is ever accessed for write.

```
Line 4:     protected int size; // number of nodes
Line 8:         size = 0;
Line 12:     public int size() {
Line 13:         return size;
Line 18:         return (size == 0);
Line 69:         if (size != 0)
Line 97:         size = 1;
Line 173:         System.out.println("Size = " + T.size());
```

And this is your size() method:

```
/** Returns the number of nodes in the tree. */
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

Main problem seems to be that `size` is essentially redundant. However, it prevents you from parsing the whole tree to determine the element count, so it can be considered a cache.

As you experienced right now, the general problem with caches and other redundant information is, that you need to carefully track them and keep them up to date. Placing some `assert` statements strategically can greatly help you with that task.

Comment: what would you suggest to change in my size method so I can get the correct height of the tree?

Comment: Two options. Either remove `size` completely, or make sure it always contains the right value. Asking `size` is O(1), while iterating the whole tree is O(N). Assuming production-ready code, the key questions are (a) how big your N may become and (b) how often you want to call size()?